# XAML usage question

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

As far as I know, XAML is only used in **WPF** and **Silverlight**, isn't it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is also used in Windows Workflow Foundation:

[Using Workflow Markup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735921(VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

XAML is also the basis for XPS.

Answer (score 0):

It is also used in Office 2007+ *x formats

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for whatever you like (beginning with .NET 4.0 if I'm not mistaken, didn't try it in 3.5).

However, if you do so, please also use the other good things .NET has to offer, such as "INotifyPropertyChanged" and dependency properties. Otherwise whatever you create will be a less - than - optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge mistake I often see people make when they say, "XAML is UI markup." It's not. You can have XAML with no UI whatsoever. XAML is, in essence, an XML object graph. It is markup for creating classes. It provides the parser with instructions on how to generate instances of types and set properties on those types. This is extremely useful for creating UI in WPF and Silverlight but can also extend to sample data, view models, and other constructs. As mentioned here, it is also used in Workflow and other areas.

Comment: Thanks. I know exactly what XAML is. But I didn't know it was used in other technologies like WorkFlow.